# Does locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method called at the same time in extension and its containing app

Tags: swift, core-location, today-extension

Here is the scenario,I have added a today extension target to my app. And in my widget ViewController, it listens to location changes via Core Location framework.Also,there is location changes listener in my containing app.And I know there is a callback to get the latest location.

```
optional func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager!,
       didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
```

However,What I want to know is that when my containing app and widget is both running(sounds werid,assuming containing app is running in background),and they are both listening to location changes using CLLocationManager,does the method locationManager:didUpdateLocations: called at the same time and get the same location data or something else?( I know widget and app is running in separate process in advance)
Thanks in advance. :-]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the updates will happen at the same time. It might be that they happen to be at the same time, but this is not guaranteed to be true, so you couldn't rely on it.

Assuming that the phone isn't moving *too* quickly, they'll probably get the same location, but there might be slight differences in when those updates are delivered to the apps.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tom Harrington that there's no guarantee.

In fact, I'd probably go a bit further and say that for many update modes, it's quite unlikely that you'll get updates at the same time and with the same location.

For example, if you've set both the extension and the app to use different `distanceFilter` or `desiredAccuracy` values, then it's only logical that they'll get different updates.

Even if they have the same values for both keys, if they were started at different times and different locations, they may exceed the thresholds (and thus receive updates) at different times.

Now, it's possible that iOS will optimise things by sending the update to both processes at once.  But I certainly wouldn't rely on it.